# Firebase-ui error

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I am trying to do phone verification using Firebase-UI  and it works correctly, but when I made a combination with  ((`firebase-database gradle` or `firebase-core graddle`)).

it doesn't work an give me this message :"

> can not access file   class file for
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeui ,
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeui not found "

here is my gradle code :

this is the working one:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "edu.maaty.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
    dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
api 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this doesn't work and give me error!!!!!!  :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "edu.maaty.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
    dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
api 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is  (buildscript).

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven{
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    }
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.2'
```

into this:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.1'
```

FirebaseUi should be compatible with firebase/ google play services

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries